# Why does my Python code thinks a variable is a str when it should be an int?

Tags: python, string, integer, typeerror

So we are making a Python program in class in which we extract data about road accidents.
The file we are extracting from is a table with each line giving information about the people involved in a given accident

```
usagers_2016 = open('usagers_2016.csv','w',encoding='utf8', errors='ignore', newline="\n")
usagers_2016.write("Num_Acc;place;catu;grav;sexe;trajet;secu;locp;actp;etatp;an_nais;num_veh\n
201600000001;1;1;1;2;0;11;0;0;0;1983;B02\n
201600000001;1;1;3;1;9;21;0;0;0;2001;A01\n
201600000002;1;1;3;1;5;11;0;0;0;1960;A01\n
201600000002;2;2;3;1;0;11;0;0;0;2000;A01\n
201600000002;3;2;3;2;0;11;0;0;0;1962;A01\n
201600000003;1;1;1;1;1;11;0;0;0;1997;A01\n")

next(usagers_2016)

dict_acc = {}

for ligne in usagers_2016.readlines():
    ligne = ligne[:-2].split(";")
```

I chose to extract the info in a dictionnary, where the accident is the key, the value of each key is a list, whose first element is a list of the people involved, each person being represented by a list including their gender and birth year

```
    if ligne[0] not in dict_acc.keys():
        dict_acc[ligne[0]] = [[],0,0,0,0]
    dict_acc[ligne[0]][0].append([ligne[4],ligne[10]])

usagers_2016.close()

for accident in dict_acc:
    accident[1] = len(accident[0]) # TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

My problem is the following: I want to add, as the second element of the main list (the value of the key), the number of people involved in each accident (which is the `len()` of the first element (list) of the list). However it was revealed during the running of the code that the first 0 (line 2 of the previous code extract) is considered a `str` and can't receive item assignment whatsoever. The problem is that it was supposed to be an `int`!!!! I thought that expliciting the `int` type as following `dict_acc[ligne[0]] = [[],int(0),int(0),int(0),int(0)]` would correct it, but no, my 0s are still considered strings. Would you know why?

Comment: you can post a sample of `usagers_2016.csv` so others can run the code, also fwiw you are better off reading this using `csv.reader`

Comment: Can you plea explain in which line in your code you are getting the error

Comment: @NirElbaz the error is in the last line: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: `split()` returns a list of strings. This is true even if the string consists entirely of numbers. Have your code call `int()` on the column values you are expecting to be numeric. And be prepared for the situation where the data is not what you expect.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do in that line, or why you expect it to work. Can you please clarify? Note that ``for accident in dict_acc:`` will iterate over the *keys* of the dictionary, and as you say yourself "where the accident is the key". For the first entry, the key ``accident`` is ``"201600000001"``, so ``accident[1]`` is ``"0"`` and your code tries to set this. *Even if the keys were numbers this does not make sense.* While strings do not support item assignment, numbers have no notion of items at all.

Comment: If I udnerstand correctly what you want is to have a new fields with the numnber of passenger involved in the accident? If each row represents one vehicle, which colum represents the number of passengers per vehicle injured in the accident? `place`, `catu`, `grav`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi OK thanks so much, I thought I was calling the [1] element of the values

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre none of the columns of the original table have the information of numbers of people involved, I have to calculate it

Comment: how do I close the question? the answer was @MisterMiyagi 's comment

for accident in dict_acc:
 dict_acc[accident][1] = len(dict_acc[accident][0])

Comment: You can accept your own answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i have to wait 2 days but yes

Answer (score 1):

OK so the problem was that I was calling `accident[1]` instead of `dict_acc[accident][1]`

solution is

```
for accident in dict_acc:
    dict_acc[accident][1] = len(dict_acc[accident][0])
```

I thank @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are reading the file with open you have an object of type `_io.TextIOWrapper` and each line is a string, which you are later splitting based on the delimeter `';'`.

The line `next(usagers_2016)` makes me think you are dropping the first row with headers.

So what you could do instead is to open this csv as a Dataframe in Pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('usagers_2016.csv', sep=';')
# To remove the tailing \n
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(r'\n','')
df.replace(r'\\n','', regex=True)

# Now to calculate the number of people involve in each accident you can
df.groupby(['Num_Acc']).size()
```

Comment: This won't fix that their operation ``accident[1] = len(accident[0])`` makes no sense, no matter if it is performed on a string or integer.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are right that is not fixing. With my answer the user at least can get the fields in different columns. I believe now she is trying to group by key, that is first column in her file `Num_Acc`, and the count how many people was injured in the accident,  which I believe is column `catu`. The thing is the approach she is trying to follow is gonna be super complex, when by using dataframes, her operations may look like more intuitive and easier even to ask

Comment: I doubt that operations such as ``df.columns.str.replace(r'\\n','')`` are particularly intuitive unless one is familiar with pandas. (I also still don't get why you remove ``r'\\n'`` instead of ``'\n'``.) Either way, regardless of what is intuitive or not it does not fix the problem in any way.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi in the file she shared there is an additional `\n` at the end of each line, even for headers. And if she confirms what is the count she is trying to achieve I will edit my anwser

Comment: The data shown in the questions contains ``\n``, aka a single newline character. ``r'\\n'`` are three characters, namely ``\``, ``\`` and ``n``, since ``r`` disables escapes and ``\\`` would be an escaped ``\``.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre the column catu is something else, the table is made such as each line represents a person, you can only know how many people are involved in a same accident by counting the lines with the same Num_Acc

Comment: @Amaia so you ultimate goal is to calculate how many people was involved in each accident? like to end up with a table saying for accident 201600000001 2 people was involved, for accident 201600000002 3 people...? Is this your ultimate goal?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so you mean this should work `df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(r'\n','')`, This is the problem you find?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre yes, ultimate goal of this line of code, but not of the whole code
Anyways MiserMiyagi found the problem

Comment: @Amaia yeah, I am aware that the line was wrong, my answer was trying to show you an alternative way of achieving the same just faster. Once you have it in a `df`, a `groupby` and a `size` should be getting the result you are trying to achieve

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre It should be ``df.columns.str.replace('\n','')``. Note that it is neither a raw string literal, nor does it escape the ``\``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Hi, please dont think I was ignoring you, just it is not working for me. I reproduce what she added in the question and the last header remains as `num_veh\n`. I am not sure if it is due to the actual `\n` string which is at the end of each line (besides the new line that separates each element) or if the solution you mentioned is not working in Python3 in Jupiter, but when testing it for me it remains as `num_veh\n`, that is why I didn't correct my answer. However I appreciate you comments, I didnt know that `r` disables escapes. So that is something I get new